# Getting InvalidClassException when using PutIgniteCache processor in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, ignite

I am trying to put some FlowFiles into my Ignite cache by using the PutIgniteCache processor in NiFi but get some mismatch in SerialVersionUID from what I can see. Any idea how I can solve this?

I am using NiFi version 1.9.0, Ignite version 1.6.0 and Java 8.

**Here are the errors I am getting:**

```
[10:28:09,862][SEVERE][tcp-disco-msg-worker-#2%null%][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to unmarshal discovery custom message.
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal(JdkMarshaller.java:105)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractMarshaller.java:78)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.messages.TcpDiscoveryCustomEventMessage.message(TcpDiscoveryCustomEventMessage.java:80)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.notifyDiscoveryListener(ServerImpl.java:4894)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processCustomMessage(ServerImpl.java:4750)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processMessage(ServerImpl.java:2320)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processMessage(ServerImpl.java:2121)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorkerAdapter.body(ServerImpl.java:6007)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.body(ServerImpl.java:2208)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.cache.configuration.MutableConfiguration; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 201405, local class serialVersionUID = 201306200821
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:699)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1885)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1885)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:797)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2178)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal(JdkMarshaller.java:102)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: FWIW, this looks like an actionable bug on our part (I'm on the NiFi PMC). I would recommend you take this over to our user list here, so we can start a discussion on it.

http://nifi.apache.org/mailing_lists.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have mixed JCache 1.0 with JCache 1.1 (on different nodes on indeed on same one). Make sure that only one version of JCache is in classpath (`cache-api-*.jar`)